# Must the Default.png launch image contain the status bar, or not?

Tags: ios

I can't remember. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does on the iPhone, but not on the iPad. From the iOS App Programming Guide:

[image]

Comment: so I guess the status bar should be a black or gray empty rectangle with no text?

Comment: @openfrog no, you leave the status bar in; it just gets cropped out on the iPhone. (It's all a little inconsistent, I know...)

Comment: it doen't get cropped out on the launch animation sequence. Example: Try to make a red status bar, and while the image gets bigger and bigger during the animation you can see the red thing.

Comment: I don't understand... you have a launch image with a red status bar, but your app has a non-red status bar?

Comment: @ShaggyFrog what do you mean by leave the status bar in? What are you supposed to put where the status bar goes? I'm guessing just the status bar background since the other elements can change.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale "Leave the status bar in" the screenshot means to not crop it out. It's 20 pixels tall and accounts for the 20 pixel discrepancy between the dimensions in the table above and the size of the screen (1024x768)

Comment: @ShaggyFrog That doesn't answer the question MattDiPasquale asked. The status bar has variable content. What should be shown in that region on the screenshot?